# Adding points and their relative legend with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$s$},ylabel={$c$},legend pos=south east]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus] coordinates
{(0.3,0.275)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=10$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus] coordinates
{(0.2,0.15)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=10$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x] coordinates
{(0.345743, 0.332178)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=15$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x] coordinates
{(0.154257, 0.0928216)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=15$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the picture below:

[image]

In the legend I'd like only one description for different kinds of point. For example, we have that the cases 10 and 15 are repeated two times. The correct picture should be that:

[image]

**EDIT**

However, the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$s$},ylabel={$c$},legend pos=south east]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus] coordinates
{(0.3,0.275)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus] coordinates
{(0.2,0.15)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=10$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x] coordinates
{(0.345743, 0.332178)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x] coordinates
{(0.154257, 0.0928216)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=15$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=o] coordinates
{(0.361803,0.352254)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=o] coordinates
{(0.138197, 0.0727458)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=20$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=square] coordinates
{(0.370416, 0.36302)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=square] coordinates
{(0.129584, 0.0619801)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=25$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

does not solve my problem:

[image]

Comment: How about invoking the respective `\addlegendentry` only once instead of twice?

Comment: I've edited my post. Unfortunately I have another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should never forget about the option `forget plot`, which allows you to disregard a plot for a legend. I added this to every other plot to obtain

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.7,xlabel={$s$},ylabel={$c$},legend pos=south east]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus] coordinates
{(0.3,0.275)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=oplus,forget plot] coordinates
{(0.2,0.15)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=10$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x] coordinates
{(0.345743, 0.332178)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=x,forget plot] coordinates
{(0.154257, 0.0928216)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=15$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=o] coordinates
{(0.361803,0.352254)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=o,forget plot] coordinates
{(0.138197, 0.0727458)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=20$}
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=square] coordinates
{(0.370416, 0.36302)};
\addplot+[smooth,draw=black,mark=square,forget plot] coordinates
{(0.129584, 0.0619801)};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta=25$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]